# object instance has larger array length than the provided arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here there are three constructor functions Person,Books,Library.Now for Library part i send it two instances as argument which i have created using book constructor.everything is ok but the problem is i have sent only two arguments

```
var newlib=new Library(storyBook,horrorBook);
```

the problem is in this part:

```
function Library(){
   this.book=new Array(arguments.length);
       console.log('length of book array : '+this.book.length);
       console.log('argument length : '+arguments.length);
   for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
       this.book.push(arguments[i]);


   }

   this.getbookslist=function (){

   for(var i=0;i<this.book.length;i++){
      document.body.innerHTML+=this.book[i].name+'</br>';
   }
}
}

var newlib=new Library(storyBook,horrorBook);
console.log('newlib book list length : '+newlib.book.length);
```

but console giving me that `newlib.book.length` has array of length 4.while `this.book` has length 2.what might be the reason for this problem.

**code**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

function Person(lastname,firstname){
  this.lastname=lastname;
  this.firstname=firstname;
  this.fullname=this.firstname+' '+this.lastname;
}
var mrX=new Person("X","mr");
var mrY=new Person('Y','mr');
var mrZ=new Person('Z','mr');

function Book(name,price,page){
    this.name=name;
    this.price=price;
    this.page=page;
    this.author=new Array(arguments.length-3);
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length-3;i++){
        this.author[i]=arguments[i+3];

    }

}
var storyBook=new Book('story','200','60',mrX);
var horrorBook=new Book('horror ','100','50',mrY,mrZ);
function Library(){
   this.book=new Array(arguments.length);
       console.log('length of book array : '+this.book.length);
       console.log('argument length : '+arguments.length);
   for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
       this.book.push(arguments[i]);


   }

   this.getbookslist=function (){

   for(var i=0;i<this.book.length;i++){
      document.body.innerHTML+=this.book[i].name+'</br>';
   }
}
}

var newlib=new Library(storyBook,horrorBook);
console.log('newlib book list length : '+newlib.book.length);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't pre-size: this.author=[]; this.book=[];

Comment: why that's a problem???

Comment: If you just want to convert `arguments` to an array, do `this.books = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);`.

Comment: well thanks.but here i just gave this.book array a length equal to the length of provided arguments using this.book=new Array(arguments.length)i didn't try to implement any array method on the arguments!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your call to `new Array(arguments.length)`. This initializes an empty array with a `length` of `2`. The `push` method inserts values based on the array's current `length` value.

Consider this simple example:

```
var a = new Array(2);
a.push("foo");
console.log(a);
```

This logs `[undefined, undefined, "foo"]` (or `[undefined x 2, "foo"]`, depending on your browser). The `push` operation performs an insert at index `2`, because that is the array's `length` at the time the `push` is performed.

Instead, initialize an array with an initial length of `0` by doing `new Array()` or (even better) just `[]`.